# Coefficient field of a newform using Magma

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, computational-number-theory, magma

It is well-known that, for a newform $f = \sum c_nq^n \in \Gamma_0(N)$, the coefficient field $K_f := \mathbb{Q}(a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots )$ is a number field.

I am introducing myself in Magma, and I was wondering (because I failed to find a reference for this) if there is a way to find, for a newform as an input, the number field associated using Magma. I am interested in this, because later on I want to compute the $\text{Norm}_{K_f/\mathbb{Q}} (a_l(E) - c_l)$ for some elliptic curve $E / \mathbb{Q}$.

I would deeply appreciate if anyone has a reference for this or knows the command for this.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I feel that this question is maybe a question for the Magma group and not necessarily for MO. That said, If the newform is $f$, the command is CoefficientField(f).

Comment: Sorry about that i didn't know that there was a Magma group, i will not make that mistake again! Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, when I say contacting the Magma group, I mean e-mailing magma@maths.usyd.edu.au.

Comment: Does it have to be Magma specifically? I could explain how to do this in Sage if you like.

Comment: yeah in need it in Magma, basically because all the other things i have done for my problem are in Magma and i have never used Sage before.

Answer (score 8):

Here is code in Sage which does what you're asking for:

```
sage: t = cputime() 
....: f = Newforms(123, names='a')[3]
....: print(f.hecke_eigenvalue_field())
....: E = EllipticCurve('389a')
....: for p in prime_range(1000): 
....:     print(p, (E.ap(p) - f[p]).norm()) 
....: print( "Time %.3f sec" % (cputime() - t))
```

This took 0.8 seconds on my machine. This can almost certainly be done more or less equally easily in Magma or PARI/GP too.

EDIT. Here's code doing the same thing in Magma:

```
T := Time();
E := EllipticCurve("389a1");
f := Newforms(CuspForms(Gamma0(123), 2))[4][1];
for p in PrimesUpTo(1000) do
    [p, Norm(FrobeniusTraceDirect(E, p) - Coefficient(f, p))];
end for; 
Time(T);
```

Magma seems to be a shade faster (0.7 seconds to 0.8) but there's very little in it. I haven't tried coding this up in PARI -- the functionality certainly exists but I'm not so familiar with how to use it. <s>Maybe someone else can weigh in for comparison</s> EDIT: François Brunault has kindly provided a PARI/GP code sample in the comments below.

Comment: Here is a Pari/GP code:
E = ellinit("389a1");
mf = mfinit([123, 2]);
f = mfeigenbasis(mf)[4];
v = mfcoefs(f, 1000);
forprime(p = 2, 1000, print([p, norm(ellap(E, p) - v[p+1])]));
It took approx 0.35s. An important point is to precompute all the coefficients (otherwise, it surprisingly took 18s). I tried the same trick in Magma but it didn't speed up much (0.35s vs 0.42s).

Comment: Excuse me i have a question about this code, in "Norm(FrobeniusTraceDirect(E, p) - Coefficient(f, p))]."
 How does the command "Norm" recognize that i want to compute the field norm, with respect to $K_f/\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @TomásSeguel Every object that you can define in Magma has an associated Type, which you can obtain by calling `Type`. In this case, calling `Type(FrobeniusTraceDirect(E, p) - Coefficient(f, p));` yields `FldNumElt`, which is an object that has a function `Norm`. If you want to know more about this particular function, you can search for `Norm` in the Magma Handbook and find the corresponding entry for `FldNumElt` (you'll see that there are many `Norm` functions). Another useful Magma function is to call `Parent` on objects. Similar things apply for Sage and PARI/GP.

Answer (score 3):

David and François have given nice answers to the question at hand. More generally for questions like "How do I do $X$ in Sage/Magma/PARI/GP?", you could consult the respective reference manuals: [Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/), [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/), [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html-stable/).

Also, do consider checking out the [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/). There you can find lots of code snippets for constructing these objects (e.g. for [elliptic curves](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/475776/ba/1) you can click the respective "Show commands for" button). For your question of Newforms in Magma, there is a "Modular form to Magma" download option (see e.g.  [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/1071/2/i/e/), on the right) which gives you lots of additional information, and studying the code in that file (as well as the analogous ones for Sage and PARI/GP) is a good way of getting better at mathematical programming in these languages.